# convert dd MMM yyyy to unix time

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have a string I'm pulling from a file in the format of `dd MMM yyyy` which I'd like to convert to `unixtime` to monitor on.

As an example:

```
19 Jul 2017
```

I want to display as:

```
1500422400
```

Per some searching I'm trying the following:

```
$dateValue = "19 Jul 2017"
$date1 = Get-Date -Date "01/01/1970"
$date2 = Get-Date -Date $dateValue
$unixtime = Get-Date (New-TimeSpan -Start $date1 -End $date2).TotalSeconds
```

I get the following error:

> Get-Date : Cannot bind parameter 'Date'. Cannot convert value
>   "1530662400" to type "System.DateTime". Error: "String was not 
>   recognized as a valid DateTime." At D:\cppib\bin\snlStatus.ps1:19
>   char:22
>   + $unixtime = Get-Date (New-TimeSpan -Start $date1 -End $date2).TotalSeconds
>   +                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Date], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetDateCommand

Comment: Remove Get-Date in list line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `Get-Date` in list line as it is trying to convert the Timespan's total seconds into a `DateTime`.

```
$dateValue = "19 Jul 2017"
$unixtime = ((Get-Date $dateValue)-(Get-Date "01 JAN 1970")).TotalSeconds
Write-Host $unixtime
```

Further checks found this

```
$dateValue = "19 Jul 2017"
$unixtime = Get-Date $dateValue -UFormat %s
Write-Host $unixtime
```

which returned the same thing.

Source: [Get-Date](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date)

Answer (score 1):

```
$unixstart = Get-Date -Date "01/01/1970"
$date2 = Get-Date $dateValue

$unixtime = (New-TimeSpan -Start $unixstart -End $date2).TotalSeconds

Write-Host $unixtime
```